# SanitizeHelper removes permitted tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is a sample comment I'm trying to sanitize:

`"<p><strong>hello</strong><em></em> <em>there</em> <a href=\"https://google.com\" title=\"Test\" target=\"_blank\">whats</a> up?</p><p><ul><li>this&nbsp;</li><li>is a</li><li>list</li></ul><p>and then there was more</p><p><ol><li>do this</li><li>do that</li></ol><p><img src=\"https://google.com\" alt=\"\"><br></p></p></p>"`

I tried sanitizing with this command:

`sanitize comment.text, tags: %w(p, strong, em, a, blockquote, img, ol, ul, li), attributes: %w(href, target, title)`

Output is:

`"hello there whats up?<li>this </li><li>is a</li><li>list</li>and then there was more<li>do this</li><li>do that</li>"`

As you can see the `li` elements aren't nested in their respective ordered and unordered lists, and all the other tags I tried to permit are removed too.

Comment: See comments on answer to see why I'm closing.

Answer (score 4):

When using the special array creators (such as `%w()` you don't want to use commas:

```
%w(p, strong, em, a, blockquote, img, ol, ul, li)
# => ["p,", "strong,", "em,", "a,", "blockquote,", "img,", "ol,", "ul,", "li"]
```

Remove those and things should start working for you. (You'll note that `li` worked, because as the last element, it didn't contain a trailing comma)

Comment: Ah, I feel like a dumbass now, thanks. I'm going to remove this question since it really doesn't solve any problems other than reminding me how to write basic ruby array creators.

Comment: Oops I can't delete it, I guess I'll just vote to close.

Comment: yeah usually I just leave a comment and VTC as a typo for questions like this, but honestly this specific error (commas in `%w()` has come up a ton (especially recently)) so the "resolved in a way unlikely to help future readers" part of that clause doesn't seem to be fitting, so decided to go with an actual answer this time